# Cisco 3945 Switch and SM-D-ES3G-48-P service-module issue

Tags: cisco

Cisco 3945 Switch and SM-D-ES3G-48-P service-module comms issue

Hi folks,

Let me try and explain my situation.

I have the 3945 switch and 48 port etherswitch module.

The 3945 ios and config are setup correctly !

The etherswitch on the otherhand, im unable to access as i stupidly ran

> switch # baud 57600

within the rommon, my problem now is that i am unable to access the rommon

some configs i have

```
bifrost-cisco3945#service-module GigabitEthernet4/0 status
Service Module is Cisco GigabitEthernet4/0
Service Module supports session via TTY line 259
Service Module is trying to recover from error
Service Module reset on error is disabled
Service Module heartbeat-reset is enabled
Service Module status is not available
bifrost-cisco3945#

line 259
 no activation-character
 no exec
 transport preferred none
 transport input all
 transport output pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
 stopbits 1
 flowcontrol hardware


bifrost-cisco3945#service-module GigabitEthernet4/0 session
Trying 192.168.1.38, 2259 ... Open


User Access Verification

Username: xxx
Password:
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒枘▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒枘▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
```

When i try and connect i get wierd characters, probably from me setting incorrect baud

bifrost-cisco3945(config-line)#speed 57600
 Only baud rates 9600 and 115200 are supported
Failed to change line 259's speed
bifrost-cisco3945(config-line)#

i can only set 9600 and 115200 on the line 259

so

etherswitch on 57600 baud
router on 9600 baud

so there is miscommunication between router and switch module

how can i fix this ?? there doesnt appear to be any reset switches anywhere on the module,
there is a 12 pin pcb header, but not sure what this does, there must be some serial connection between 
etherswitch pcb and the router pcb but i do not know the pin outs :(

Comment: Did you save the config after utilizing `baud 57600`? If not, you could reload the whole switch or power it off shortly.

Comment: i did baud 57600 in rommon, there was no saving to do, it made it permanant

Comment: rommon on the switch module that is

Comment: the prompt was switch #